# Attaching dojo events in ArcGIS Javascript API 3.29

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am trying to do same job for two different events on map using dojo on() function.

```
map.on('extent-change', function (event) {
//code goes here
}
```

and

```
map.on('zoom-end', function () {
//same code goes here
}
```

Is there any way that I could attach the events or do the same thing for both without writing the code again?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one [listener to multiple events](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html#multiple-events) in dojo

```
on(domNode, "click, focus", function(e){
    // handle both events 
  });
```

That said I do not think [Esri library](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_events.html) supports to listen multiple events using one event listener.